# Gravar ou remover acentuação em um TextAreaFor

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Olá.

Tenho um ***TextAreaFor*** que recebe o conteúdo em HTML, entretanto ao salvar os dados, os acentos e caracteres especiais ficam codificados e tenho problemas depois ao editar ou visualizar os dados.

**View de cadastro:**

```
div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Preparo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-form-label" })
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Preparo, new  { @class = "form-control", @rows = 15, @value = "Digite o procedimento ou código, irá autocompletar"  })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Preparo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

**View de listagem:**

```
  @Html.Raw(item.Preparo)
```

**Model:**

```
 [Required]
 [AllowHtml]
 public string Preparo { get; set; }
```

[image: Visualização da parte do usuário]

Como poderia exibir o texto com os acentos para o usuário?

Comment: tem que colocar um editor em html um exemplo: http://www.macoratti.net/17/03/mvc_rctbx1.htm

Comment: Olá @VirgilioNovic, obrigado pelo comentário, mas este não é o problema, eu já possuo um editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro ocorria por dois motivos:

1º A string gerada em html era convertida para maiúsculo, antes de chegar ao controller.

2º precisei utilizar o método `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()`, da seguinte maneira.

```
Preparo = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(preparoExame.Preparo);
```

Você pode acessar a documentação aqui: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmldecode?view=netframework-4.8

**Como ficou:**

**View de cadastro**: repare foi adicionado na propriedade da classe `ignore-uppercase`

```
<div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Preparo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-form-label" })
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Preparo, new  { @class = "form-control ignore-uppercase", @rows = 15, @value = "Digite o procedimento ou código, irá autocompletar"  })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Preparo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

**View da listagem:**

```
<td data-title="Preparo">
     @Html.Raw(item.Preparo)
</td>
```

[image: Listagem dos preparos com acentuação.]

**Controller:**
[image: HttpUtility.HtmlDecode() no controller]

Answer (score 0):

Como você já esta usando [AllowHtml] no atributo verifique se está usando

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

no head do da página.

Isso poderia ocasionar nesse problema.
ps: verifica como os a caracteres estão chegando no controller

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. No controller chega como está na listagem de preparos, o head está correto.

Comment: havia escrito 
<meta charset="UTF-8">
na no texto mas sumiu

Answer (score 0):

Considere verificar as configuraçoes relativas a globalização de caracteres, veja as soluções abaixo:

1 - No seu html, verifique se existe a tag referente a conversão de caracteres, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```

Se ela não existir dentro da tag `head` inclua.

**O erro persiste?**

2 - no seu web.Config certifique-se de incluir o código:

```
<globalization fileEncoding="utf-8" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="pt-br"/>
```

Ele afeta diretamente a conversão de caracteres nos arquivos.

**Ainda não?**

3- Altere a tag meta onde está `utf-8` para `ISO-8859-1`.

Certemente estas auterações vão resolver o seu erro.

Se em **último caso**, persistir. Como condição final podemos estabelecer que o [encoding](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-choosing-encodings.pt-br) dos arquivos está diferênte do esperado, sabendo disso siga estes passos pelo visual studio: `ferramentas/opções/ambiente/documentos/` e altere a opção `Salve documentos como Unicode quando os dados não puderem ser salvos`.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, entretanto não é este o caso, senão todas as páginas estariam com problema.

Comment: outras páginas tem as consultas?

Comment: Sim, mas não da mesma maneira que está.

Comment: Eu já encontrei a solução, obrigado pela atenção.